# PHP check value of CheckBox?

Tags: php, html

I have 10 checkboxes, like so

```
<input type="hidden" name="box1" value="0"><input type="checkbox" id="box1" name="box1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="box2" value="0"><input type="checkbox" id="box2" name="box2" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="box3" value="0"><input type="checkbox" id="box3" name="box3" value="1">
```

and so forth. These checkboxes are all inside a form, and when submitted will go to a PHP script. How am I able to access the values (on or off) for each one. So far I have tried using this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="box[]" value="0"><input type="checkbox" id="box1" name="box[]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="box[]" value="0"><input type="checkbox" id="box2" name="box[]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="box[]" value="0"><input type="checkbox" id="box3" name="box[]" value="1">
```

with

```
$x = $_POST["box"];
foreach ($x as $y){
    echo $y . "</br>";
}
```

But this gives random, inaccurate results (say for example box 1, 3 and 4 are clicked, it may give something like this: [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], with 1 being on and 0 off). Can anyone give me a hint in the right direction? Thank you in advance

Comment: what are the hidden fields for?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Without them, the values that are 0 dont show when echo'd by PHP.

Comment: You have to remember that UNCHECKED checkboxes are not returned to the script. You therefore have to test if the checkbox exists in the $_POST array, normally using a simple `if ( isset($_POST['box'][0] )` etc etc probably in a loop in your case

Comment: the hidden boxes makes no sense at all

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a checkbox has been checked by using `isset($_POST['checkbox_name'])` which returns true if it is checked and false if it is not.

For example;

```
if(isset($_POST['box1'])){
  //do something positive
}
```

I do not think you need the other hidden fields.